# Will money be transferred alongside my character if I move from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If I transfer my character from Xbox 360 to XBone will my GTA money in my 'cash' section transfer to my Xbox One character?

Answer (score 1):

On the [Rockstar website regarding transfers](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC) you can find this:

"All earned in-game money will transfer. Purchased in-game money that has not yet been spend will only transfer within a same console family (e.g.Xbox 360 to Xbox One)"

I'm pretty sure this includes cash.

But even though I recommend putting all your cash on your bank account before transferring, 'just in case' especially when you have a lot of cash.